# What is the correct order of the sort callback function parameters?

Tags: javascript

You can see literraly **everywhere**(youtube, articles) that the **"a"** and **"b"** parameters of the js **sort** method correspond to respectively the **first** and **second** element of the array.
That's *wrong*, take a look :

```js
const numbers = [3,2,1];

numbers.sort((a, b) => {
  console.log(a,b);
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);
```

The console looks like this :

```
2 3
1 2
[1, 2, 3]
```

We clearly see that the values of "a" and "b" in the first execution of the callback **are 2 and 3.**
This is against all logics aha !

Don't get me wrong I completely **understood** this function and the sorting algorithm beneath it, but why "a" is not equal to the first **element of the array ?** :)

And why there are tons of articles and youtube videos saying that "a" is equal to the first element of the array which is actually **not true at all ?**

Comment: The sorting algorithm used by `Array#sort` is completely implementation-dependent. Hence, all calls made to the callback can also differ in different JS engines.

Comment: "*You can see literraly everywhere that the "a" and "b" parameters of the js sort method correspond to respectively the first and second element of the array.*" - uh, that's completely wrong. The comparison function compares *arbitrary* values from anywhere in the array, and *different* values on every invocation (the argument `1` to in the second call is neither the first nor second value in the array at all). Can you link some videos/articles as examples please?

Answer (score 0):

> And why there are tons of articles and youtube videos saying that "a" is equal to the first element of the array

Well this is why we shouldn't believe everything we read or see. The [actual documented details](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) of how the browser should implement `sort` don't mention this. In fact it states:

> Sort items using an **implementation-defined** sequence of calls to SortCompare.

So it's entirely up to the browser how this should be implemented. Ultimately the result is the same so I can't really see why this matters.

Comment: Thank you for your resonse, so it's up to the browser.
Well the problem is that all youtubers / blog writers are saying that a = first el of array, which is not true, and you can't build a website or a software with false assomptions, even if the result is correct right ?
It leads to a global missunderstanding and sooner or later, many bugs.

Comment: Well you need to get your information from truted sources. I could stick up a you tube video saying anything, doesn't make it true. The link goes to [Tc39](https://tc39.es/) who are a **trusted source** on the actual W3c specs. Another good one is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).